# Sync selection/Select all faces workflow

Tags: texturing, uv

I have just switched over to Blender after working in Max and Maya for many years. I want to start by saying that I love Blender in so many ways. When it comes to UV editing though there are some basic workflows that I just can't get my head around. My problems arise with that I need to switch between sync selection and selecting faces on my mesh which becomes very cumbersome. So here is a typical example:

1. I generally want to see all my UVs so I use sync selection. It works fine until I want to move a UV at a border/seam. Since it's the same vertex as the opposing seam (same vertex), it moves both UVs which is not what I want.
2. I then have to turn off sync selection. I select all faces on my mesh and now it works to move a UV at a border.
3. So maybe I can always work like this I think? Noops because a while later I want to weld two UVs that share vertex but I can't see which one it is so I have to switch back to sync selection to visualize this, turn it off (or shared vertex drop-down and then switch back to disabled). Then switch back to all faces and do the weld from memory. Or if want to see which UV face corresponds to to which face on the mesh I need to be in sync selection mode since all faces are selected already.

I just don't understand how you get an efficient workflow going like this?

Ideally I would just work with sync selection 99 percent of the time BUT with the option to move UVs independently. And the second less preferred option to have all faces selected on the mesh but somehow visualize shared vertex (Not jumping between disabled/shared location/shared vertex).

So long rambling and a small cry for help :) Any tips, addons or whatnot?

Comment: I feel your pain, and really think this should change. Elaborate a well described solution and post it in right click select for voting.